# Perforce messes up symlinks

Tags: perforce

When I download source code from perforce, the symlinks gets downloaded as files and the project, of course, doesn't build. This happens on certain computers and virtual machines but the same symlinks download fine on other computers.

The download file is often a short file which just contains path of the linked file instead of being zero byte symlink file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This actually had to do with user permissions on windows, not so much with perforce. The problem is that the user doesn't have permission to create symlinks so perforce ends up creating a file (In my opinion, it should generate an error message instead of converting the symlink to file).

The simple solution in most cases should be to start P4V as administrator and then download the source code. You may have to force it to download everything since it will not re-download wrong symlinks because those objects already exist on disk.

You can check if you have permissions with the following command. More [here](http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/3472/?q=enabling&l=en_US&fs=Search&pn=1).

```
mklink <linkFile> <ExistingFile>
```

Note: you may well be able to create symlinks (=shortcuts) using File Explorer but it's the command line (above) that will determine if you have the privileges or not.

Comment: Try `p4 clean`, I haven't tested it with symlinks specifically but that's the general-purpose way to make sure that what's on disk matches what's supposed to be on disk.

Comment: Don't think permissions to mklink is the problem here. I'm able to create links as a windows user with mklink but I get a file, not a link when I sync my client.

Comment: I take that back, it is about permissions, but being able to run mklink doesn't tell you if perforce is going to work or not. As noted [here](https://portal.perforce.com/s/article/3472) if UAC is on **and** you are in the admin group the client needs to be run as administrator which is independent of whether mklink will run without a prompt or just fail. I don't actually want the symlink but annoyingly if p4 writes the file it sets it as writable. Now if the symlink is deleted the next sync will fail on Windows with "Can't clobber writable file... "